# inertion of date time combobox value into database

Tags: c#, datetime, exception, ado.net, insertion

```
 string c = "";
        string s = "";
        string d = "";
        string t = "";
        if (CarNameCombo.SelectedIndex >= 0 && SourceCombo.SelectedIndex >= 0 && DestinationCombo.SelectedIndex >= 0 && NumberOfPassengers.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        c = CarNameCombo.Items[CarNameCombo.SelectedIndex].ToString();
        s = SourceCombo.Items[SourceCombo.SelectedIndex].ToString();
        d = SourceCombo.Items[DestinationCombo.SelectedIndex].ToString();
        t = NumberOfPassengers.Items[NumberOfPassengers.SelectedIndex].ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(""+c+s+d+t);
        string date = dateTimePicker1.Text;
        string date1 = dateTimePicker2.Text;
        string x = richTextBox1.Text;
        string y = richTextBox2.Text;
        MessageBox.Show("" +date +date1);
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PRAVEEN\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=travelbooking;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into BookDetails(CarName,Source,Destination,Date,FromAddress,ToAddress,Time,Numberpassengers)VALUES('" + c + "','" + s + "','" + d + "','" + date + "','" + x + "','" + y + "' '"+ date1 + "','" + t + "'", conn)");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarName", c);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Source", s);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Destination", d);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", date);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FromAddress", richTextBox1.Text);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToAddress", richTextBox2.Text);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", date1);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Numberpassengers", t);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

I am working in a windows forms project with c# and ado. I get and exception thrown saying cannot convert date and or time from character to string, i specified the datatype in my database as time(7) and date as date....do i need to do something extra??? and this is the meesage "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"under label sql exception was unhandled.

Comment: You should post the entire error message you're getting. Also add the platform you're working on to the list of tags, otherwise the question wont be seen by people with the knowledge to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find this

```
namespace First_Csharp_app
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        String gender; //we have to define this
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
            String str = "server=MUNESH-PC;database=windowapp;UID=sa;password=123";
            String query = "insert into data (E.id,name,surname,age,gender,DOB) values ('"+this.eid_txt.text+"','"+this.nametxt.text+"','"+this.surname_txt.text+"','"+this.age_txt.text+"' , '"+this.gender+"' , '"+this.DateTimePicker1.Text+"')";
            SqlCommand cmd = new sqComamnd(query,con);
            SqlDataReader dbr;
            try
            {
                con.open();
                dbr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                MessageBox.Show("saved");
                while(dbr.read())
                {
                }
            }
            catch (Exception es)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(es.Message);
            }
        }
        private void rediobutton1.checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gender = "male";
        }
        private void rediobutton1.checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gender = "female";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DateTimePicker.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) instead of [DateTimePicker.Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.text%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and create a parameterized query that accepts this `DateTime` value instead of a text string, eg:

```
    DateTime date = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    DateTime date1 = dateTimePicker2.Value;
    ...
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
 "insert into BookDetails(CarName,Source,Destination,Date,FromAddress,ToAddress,Time,Numberpassengers) " +
" VALUES(@CarName,@Source,@Destination,@Date,@FromAddress,@ToAddress, " +
       " @Time,@NumPassengers)", conn)");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarName", c);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Source", s);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Destination", d);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", date);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FromAddress", richTextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToAddress", richTextBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", date1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Numberpassengers", t);
```

The original code failed because you passed a date formatted in an arbitrary format instead of an actual date value. SQL Server tried to interpret this string using the column's collation which didn't match the end user's locale.